# How to stream result from n parallel requests send to x clients concurrently?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have several identical api services available on different clients to which I would like to send several http-requests. This data is can be transformed into a map (`Lookup<TKey, TSource>`).
Additionally, I also want to return the response from a service as soon as it is available throught a `IAsyncEnumerable`.

A naive implementation would be to run through all requests one by one. However, I would like to make this more efficient by starting `n` requests to `x` services concurrently. Note I want to limit/throttle `n` and `x`. In other words `x` is how many clients I communicate with at once. I will not start communication with a new client until all requests has been processed.
`n` define how many parallel open request I can have to one given client at once.

Is there a preferred way to do this or can it be done better than what I have come up with?

I have tried to make a solution by using `TransformBlock` and `TransformManyBlock`, but I am not very familiar with these objects thus any feedback is appreciated.

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<TOut> ParallelForEveryEntry<TKey, TSource, TOut>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    int n,
    int x,
    Func<TSource, Task<TOut>> callback,
    CancellationToken token = default
) where TKey : notnull {
    if (!source.Any()) {
        yield break;
    }

    var linkedTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token);

    TransformManyBlock<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>, TOut> blockCollection = new(collectionByEntry => {
        var linkedToken = linkedTokenSource.Token;

        TransformBlock<TSource, TOut> blockEntry = new(callback, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() {
            CancellationToken = linkedToken,
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = x,
                EnsureOrdered = false
            });

            // Feed the block with input data
            foreach (var entry in collectionByEntry) {
                blockEntry.Post(entry);
            }
            blockEntry.Complete();

            return blockEntry.ReceiveAllAsync().ToEnumerable();
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() {
        CancellationToken = token,
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = n,
        EnsureOrdered = false
    });

    // Feed the block with input data
    foreach (var collectionByEntry in source.ToLookup(keySelector)) {
        blockCollection.Post(collectionByEntry);
    }
    blockCollection.Complete();

    // Emit the output data as they become available
    while (await blockCollection.OutputAvailableAsync()) {
        while (blockCollection.TryReceive(out var item)) {
            yield return item;
        }
    }

    // Propagate possible exception (including cancellation)
    await blockCollection.Completion;
}
```

Comment: x is how many clients I communicate with at once. I will not start communication with a new client until all requests has been processed.

n define how many parallel open request I can have to one given client at once.

@TheodorZoulias, I will update question accordingly.

Comment: Do you know beforehand all the requests that your are going to make? Or it's possible for new requests to appear while the operation is ongoing? If you want to limit yourself to the first scenario, I would suggest to change the type of the `source` from `IEnumerable<TSource>` to `IReadOnlyCollection<TSource>`, to signify that the sequence is not deferred.

Comment: I want to target .NET 6

Comment: So at any moment there might be at maximum `n * x` concurrent requests, correct?

Comment: Yes @TheodorZoulias that is correct!